# Vue laravel Axios get Request URL not same as in routelist

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

Im new in Laravel, Im trying to get data from my database 
Im following video tutorial and it works

Here's my app.js

```
let routes = [
  { path: '/pertanyaanTracer', component: require('./components/tracer/Pertanyaan_Tracer.vue') }
]
```

Here's my component function

```
loadTracerPertanyaan(){
                axios.get('api/t_tracer_pertanyaan').then(({data}) => (this.t_tracer_pertanyaan = data.data));
            },
```

and my route list

[image: My route list]

It is working and return this request url

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/t_tracer_pertanyaan
```

But, when im trying to use parameter to show specific data by searched by parameter it shows nothing

Here's my app.js with parameter

```
let routes = [
  { path: '/pertanyaanTracer/:id', component: require('./components/tracer/Pertanyaan_Tracer.vue') }
]
```

Here's my component function (form.ID_TRACER = param)

```
loadTracerPertanyaan(){
                axios.get('api/t_tracer_pertanyaan/'+this.form.ID_TRACER).then(({data}) => (this.t_tracer_pertanyaan = data.data));
            },
```

It is not working and return this request url

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/pertanyaanTracer/api/t_tracer_pertanyaan/1
```

here's the controller

```
public function index()
     {
         return t_tracer_pertanyaan::latest()->paginate(10);
     }

    public function show($id)
    {
        return t_tracer_pertanyaan::where('ID_TRACER',$id)->paginate(10);
    }
```

I don't know how this **pertanyaanTracer** appear, is there a way i just can call  http://localhost:8000/api/t_tracer_pertanyaan/1

Comment: type this link  http://localhost:8000/api/t_tracer_pertanyaan/1  directly on the browser and check what it returns as a response.

Comment: @DjellalMohamedAniss here's the result

{"current_page":1,"data":[{"ID_TRACER_PERTANYAAN":1,"PERTANYAAN":"Siapa anda?","TYPE_PERTANYAAN":"PILIHAN","ID_PARENT":1,"ID_TRACER":"1","created_at":"2019-02-23 21:24:57","updated_at":"2019-02-23 21:24:57"}],"first_page_url":"http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/t_tracer_pertanyaan\/1?page=1","from":1,"last_page":1,"last_page_url":"http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/t_tracer_pertanyaan\/1?page=1","next_page_url":null,"path":"http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/t_tracer_pertanyaan\/1","per_page":10,"prev_page_url":null,"to":1,"total":1}

Comment: nice, which means that you"re getting data, and you"re API routes are correct.

Comment: @DjellalMohamedAniss, but when i call this function loadTracerPertanyaan(), it returned Request URL: http://localhost:8000/pertanyaanTracer/api/t_tracer_pertanyaan/1, how can i return the correct one